# creating train and test datasets manually in python

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

I am trying to split the data set into train and test datasets manually meaning that I don't want to use the scikit learn package. I want split them in a way that if the row index module 4 is equal to zero, put them into the training dataset, else put them into the test dataset. I have done it in R like the following:

```
testidx = which(1:nrow(price_accommodates_bedrooms )%%4 == 0)
df_train = price_accommodates_bedrooms [-testidx, ]
df_test = price_accommodates_bedrooms[testidx, ]
```

But I am not sure how to do it in python because I am new to python. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this you can take advantage of the DataFrame index and masking:

```py
test_df = df[df.index % 4 != 0]
train_df = df[df.index % 4 == 0]
```